# Add quantity to numeric based on precision of smallest digit

Tags: sql, postgresql, math, postgresql-9.3

Say I am given the value `2` as a `NUMERIC`. I want to add `0.0001` to this `2` to get `2.0001`. If I'm given `2.01`, I want to add `0.000001` to it to get `2.010001`.

Essentially, I want to add a number that is 4 orders of magnitude smaller than the number's *last digit* (highest precision digit).

For the odd case of `2.000`, I am fine with getting either `2.0001` or `2.0000001`.

#### Stuff I looked into

I considered if there might be some sort of way of extracting this information using PostgreSQL data type functions, but I could not find any.

I also tried to think of maybe some mathematical way of computing it. I considered `log`, but that will give me info about the *highest* order of magnitude digit, not the lowest.

#### Background

This is informational. I'm only providing because if I saw someone else asking this question, my first thought would be, "What in the world are they trying to do?"

I'm fully aware this is a very strange use case. The problem I am facing is that I frequently receive `TopologyException`s from GEOS through PostGIS because of some strange precision issues. (It has to do with my input data not being especially clean. Unfortunately, I'm dealing with a large amount of data and "detect and manually fix the problem geometries" is not an option.) The value I'm dealing with is effectively a tolerance parameter. It gets fed into buffer and snapping functions. Strangely enough, varying it by this small amount is usually enough to get past the error and get the result I need. I intend to build a sort of retry-with-slightly-changed-value mechanism into some of my operations in hopes of avoiding these errors. So I'm trying to figure out how to compute this slightly changed value.

Answer (score 1):

Using simple manipulation:

```
SELECT col
 , col + POW(0.1,(LENGTH(regexp_replace(CAST(col % 1 AS VARCHAR), '[0]+$', ''))-2))*0.0001 AS result
FROM tab;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/6532a/16/0)**</kbd>

1. `col % 1` - get fraction part
2. `CAST` to string
3. `REGEX_REPLACE` - remove trailing `0`
4. `LENGTH` - get length of string - `2` (`0.` part)
5. `POW(0.1, ...)` - get multiplier
6. multiply by `0.0001`
7. add to initial value

## EDIT:

Even simpler:
number -> text -> remove trailing 0 -> append `0001` -> number

```
SELECT col,
 CAST(regexp_replace(CAST(col * 1.0 AS VARCHAR), '[0]+$', '') || '0001' AS NUMERIC(30,20)) AS result
FROM tab;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e173e/3/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═════════════╦════════════════╗
║     col     ║     result     ║
╠═════════════╬════════════════╣
║ 2           ║ 2.0001         ║
║ 2.01        ║ 2.010001       ║
║ 2.05000103  ║ 2.050001030001 ║
╚═════════════╩════════════════╝
```

Comment: Nice! Can we depend on PostgreSQL to never give back numbers like `2E-5` for the `VARCHAR` representation?

Comment: @jpmc26 I am from SQL Server world and just write it based on intuition and no previous exp in Postgresql. But you are right about scientific notation. I would like someone from Postgresql world say something about it. Probably there is something like `CONVERT(type, number, format)` in PostgreSQL to be sure.

Comment: @jpmc26 I would say that converting `NUMERIC/DECIMAL` which are fixed point number you won't get scientific notation. The scientific notation you may get with inexact numbers `FLOAT/DOUBLE PRECISION`. Anyway great riddle +1

Comment: @jpmc26 see updated, no need for fancy math operation. Simple append do the job

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to do that without `pow()`.
The query in the function uses only text manipulations and casts.
It catches a special case of an integer number.

```
create or replace function add_4_pos_digits (val numeric)
returns numeric language sql as $$
    select val+ ('.' || repeat('0', d) || '1')::numeric
    from (
        select case d when 0 then 3 else d+ 2 end d
        from (
            select strpos(reverse(rtrim(val::text, '0')), '.') d
            ) q
        ) q;
$$;

create table example (val numeric);
insert into example values (1), (1.1), (1.01), (1.00001);

select val, add_4_pos_digits(val)
from example;

   val   | add_4_pos_digits 
---------+------------------
       1 |           1.0001
     1.1 |          1.10001
    1.01 |         1.010001
 1.00001 |      1.000010001
(4 rows)
```